# Reuse generic component functions

Tags: reactjs

I'm a very new React programmer and I have no idea how to fix this. In all my forms I have the following code parts.

```
    updateFormData(field, event) {
        const { formData } = this.state;
        this.setState({ formData: { ...formData, [field]: event } });
    }

    componentLoaded = (field, data) => {
        const { loadedComponents } = this.state;
        var fieldName = field + "IsLoaded";

        this.setState({ loadedComponents: { ...loadedComponents, [fieldName]: true } });
    }

    allComponentsLoaded() {

        const { loadedComponents } = this.state;
        console.log(loadedComponents);
        for (var o in loadedComponents) {
            if (!loadedComponents[o]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    updateFormDateData(field, date) {
        var value = date != null && date.isValid() ? date.toISOString() : null;
        const { formData } = this.state;
    }
```

When in C# I would put this in a base class. What would be the best way in React to do this?

Comment: The first three methods are the same thing, just with different names and different variables names(that does the same thing). You could use just one of them

Comment: Oops, made a copy paste error. Will fix that. Thanks

Comment: You can create an [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which just passes those functions down to your component

Comment: How can you make a HOC that wraps and a child that then uses those function? For example the all Components loaded function is used in the render method.